# How to get an exact match with VLOOKUP into the current cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, parsing, microsoft-excel-2019

The name "Dodson" is on A5, the lookup is from B5, the table A16:B19, the value in the second column of the table, but am looking for the precise result of a VLOOKUP.

The formula I have is:

```
=VLOOKUP($B5,$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE)
```

students:

```
A        B       C
========================
Dodson  Silver  400
Jones   Gold    550
Clarke  Titanium    700
Ranger  Platinum    750
McKinley    Platinum    750
Broadnax    Gold    550
Burch   Titanium    700
```

price:

```
Silver   400.00 
Gold     550.00 
Titanium     700.00 
Platinum     750.00
```

Trying to get an exact match using relative and absolute cell references.

And then copied into other cells.

Not too sure about the true/false usage here, as I get odd results with “true” which should be exact.

```
Not looking to use XLOOKUP or other functions.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When setting the 4th parameter in VLookup, ask yourself "do you want misleading and confusing results?" - and then user TRUE or FALSE accordingly. For an exact match, you always specify the 4th parameter and you would always use FALSE (or 0).

Comment: thank you for all the comments, and it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you posted creates the result you describe.
For an exact match, the 4th parameter of the Vlookup must be `FALSE`
The formula was entered in cell C5 and copied down.

```
=VLOOKUP($B5,$A$16:$B$19,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: that's excellent, and thank you.